# MySQL C API: Segmentation Fault when running query from different thread

Tags: c++, mysql, c, multithreading

I have a C++ program that initiates an MySQL database and then loads GUI with threads, that access the database once at a time.

When I call the `mysql_query()` function from the main thread, it works good, but when I call it from a new thread - it crashes on segmentation fault.

This code works fine (MySQL function is called in the main thread):

```
updateQueryEngines();
```

This code crashes (MySQL function is called in the different thread):

```
std::thread *my_thread = new std::thread(&MainWindow::updateQueryEngines, this);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have an answer and I think it's important to post it here, so other people don't spend a whole day on it, as I did.

When you start a new thread that accesses the **MySQL C API**, just call within the thread, the API function `mysql_thread_init()`. This will resolve the segmentation fault problems:

```
void MainWindow::updateQueryEngines() {
    mysql_thread_init();

    ... rest of the code...
}
```

Now I am able to call this function in a new thread, without getting segmentation faults:

```
std::thread *my_thread = new std::thread(&MainWindow::updateQueryEngines, this);
```

Comment: If that init function comes with a corresponding "destroy" or "free" function, you should call it at the end of that function..